# Как с помощью JS изменить содержимое во всех div'ax сразу?

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

```js
var box = document.querySelector('.box').children;
box.textContent = '0';
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box .item');

for (var q=0; q<boxes.length; ++q) {
  boxes[q].textContent = 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я так и думал, что нужен перебор

Comment: @AndreyAlisenak, если разобрался, прими соответствующий ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: спасибо, сделал

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (var box of document.querySelector('.box').children) {
  box.textContent = '0';
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```